# download all csv files from ftp recursive

Tags: php

I am trying to get the csv files from from different folders on FTP  recursiverly, but  getting an error while trying to download, I searched most of the questions but not releavent to the situation where I am struck.

```
FTP: csv file location
/home/lanein1/ftpfiles/AIN/2021-07-14/AIN.csv
/home/lanein1/ftpfiles/AOUT/2021-07-14/AOUT.csv
/home/lanein1/ftpfiles/BIN/2021-07-14/BIN.csv
/home/lanein1/ftpfiles/AOUT/2021-07-14/BOUT.csv
```

I can get to the directory ftpfiles and do a pregmatch , but I am getting Invalid argument supplied foreach()

Code:

```
$login_result = ftp_login($con, usr,pwd);
 ftp_pasv($con, true);
 basedir = /home/lanein1/ftpfiles/ --- this is were i am stuck to pass the   different folders
 $path =  'basedir'.date('Y.m.d',strtotime("-1 days"));
 $files = ftp_nlist($con,$path);
   {
   foreach ($files as  $file)
        { 
        if (preg_match("/\.csv$/i", $file))
        {
            echo" Found $file\n";
          ftp_get($con, $file, FTP_BINARY);
        }
        else
       {
        echo "not Found";
    
      }
}    
 ftp_close($con);
```

Comment: Have you tried printing what `ftp_nlist` returns?

Comment: Yes thats because your current path variable is not a valid path. The reason is `ftp_nlist` won't return directories recursively. Try modifying your path to only` /home/lanein1/ftpfiles` then check the output of `nlist`.

Comment: Yes, it can print all the folders on /home/lanein1/ftpfiles/

Comment: I can get to that point , but dont understand how to get to the date folders

Comment: To reach the date folder you will have to again call nlist on $file like                                                `foreach($files as $file) { $dir = ftp_nlist($con, $file);  print_r($dir);                           foreach($dir as $df) { print_r(ftp_nlist($con, $file)); } }`

Comment: I still get the same error invalid argument supplied at the second foreach loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234961/discussion-between-kiran-v-and-shahiq572).

Answer (score 1):

You should try one more for each loop. I've written the below script based on the description. It might not be perfect as I did not test anything. You may need to change it a little bit :)

```
$login_result = ftp_login($con, $usr,$pwd);
ftp_pasv($con, true);
$path_to_ftpfiles = "/home/lanein1/ftpfiles/";
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days")); // correct date format
$files = ftp_mlsd($con, $path_to_ftpfiles); // use ftp_mlsd
$supported_types = [
            'text/plain',
            'application/csv',
            'application/x-csv',
            'text/csv',
            'text/plain',            
        ];
if(!empty($files)){ // check if files exist
    foreach ($files as $file){ 
        if ($file["type"] == "dir"){ // check if it's directory               
            $child_folder_files = ftp_mlsd($con, "$path_to_ftpfiles/{$file["name"]}/$date/"); // get child dir files
            if(!empty($child_folder_files)){ // check if files exist inside child directory
                foreach ($child_folder_files as $child_file){ 
                    if ($child_file["type"] != "dir" && in_array(mime_content_type($child_file),$supported_types){     
                      $random_number = random_int(100000, 999999); // generate 6 digit random number if multiple files present in folder
                      $local_file = "{$child_file['name']}_$random_number.csv";  
                      $server_file = $child_file;                     
                      ftp_get($con, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII); // get csv
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

You can bypass mime_content_type check if only CSV files present inside the date folder

```
if(!empty($child_folder_files)){ // check if files exist inside child directory
    foreach ($child_folder_files as $child_file){ 
        if ($child_file["type"] != "dir"){     
          $random_number = random_int(100000, 999999); // generate 6 digit random number if multiple files present in folder
          $local_file = "{$child_file['name']}_$random_number.csv"; 
          $server_file = $child_file;                     
          ftp_get($con, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII); // get csv
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, It did not work  , I get illegal string offset 'type ' error  on this line  --  if ($child_file["type"] != "dir")

Comment: What about if you comment out that line? As I mentioned, you need to modify it a little bit.

Comment: Ravi, I got to a point where I can get  folders from Mysql table  which would be my basedir , I am just stuck how to pass yesterday date on that line.  $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 days"));  $files = ftp_nlist($con,$server['basedir']"/date/"); I  only need to get date here. can you check this

Comment: If you want to pass only date then you need to write `$files = ftp_nlist($con,"{$server['basedir']}/$date");`

Comment: Ravi , I tried you script , I am not getting any errors , but not printing anything too

Comment: that should print   the csv filename from yesterday right?

Comment: Please debug each line. You'll have a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I checked loading for my `ftp` and `js` files - it works correctly. I had created `static\js` in my `Desktop` before run code.

```
$basedir = '/static'; // I setted path as string;
$path = $basedir.'/js';

$files = ftp_nlist($con, $path);
foreach ($files as $file)
{ 
    if (preg_match("/\.js$/i", $file))
    {
      echo" Found $file\n";
      ftp_get($con, '~/home/daniil/Desktop'. $file, $file);
    }
    else
    {
      echo "other file\n"; // found but it doesn't match
    }
}
```

according to documentation:

```
 ftp_get(
    resource $ftp,
    string $local_filename,  <--- both are needed
    string $remote_filename, <---
    int $mode = FTP_BINARY,  <--- default value
    int $offset = 0
): bool
```

Comment: thanks Daniil., Its wont work  due to my base path is different    for each folder  and each folder has got different date folders on it.

Comment: in this case, we can also be slightly corrected and processed in a loop when there are full paths to folders.

Comment: thats where I am struck from past few days